# How to VLookup on second column and get first column value?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have a sheet which has two columns. Column 'A' holds names of persons and column 'B' holds employee IDs.

I read VLookup takes first column of the range for lookup. In my case, I have to VLookup on column B and get the corresponding value from column A.

I am trying this code but obviously it won't work.

```
strEmp = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(strEID, wsLookup.Range("B:A").Value, 1, False)
```

** Attempted **

Attempted solution suggested as one of the answer. Still not getting.

```
strEmp = WorksheetFunction.Match(strEID, wsLookup.Range("A2:B500"), 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH`.

Use `MATCH` to find the row on column B which has the employee ID you are looking for. Then use the `INDEX` function to find the corresponding name in column A

Comment: Attempted 'Match'. Still not getting. Please check updated original post with the attempted code.

Comment: You will need to use MATCH inside of INDEX as shown in the example below.

`Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3:C13"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D3:D13"), 0), 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You only really need `Match` in VBA:

```
Dim TableRange as Range
Set TableRange = wsLookup.Range("A:B")
Dim matchRow
matchRow = Application.Match(strEID,TableRange.Columns(2), 0)
If Not Iserror(matchRow) then strEmp = TableRange.Cells(matchrow, 1)
```